# Emacs - suppress Completion Buffer

Tags: emacs, terminal, customization, ido

In Emacs, I don't want the *Completions* buffer to pop up, even when I press tab to autocomplete in the minibuffer and there are multiple results.
It's distracting and jarring.

How can I do this?

Even better, I would like an alternative that isn't distracting or jarring -- such as requiring one tab for autocomplete if available, but requiring two tabs to open a Completions buffer. This way, I don't get the Completions buffer when I'm expecting an autocomplete. This is what the OS X terminal does to show tab completion possibilities.

I think the cause is the minibuffer-completion-help  command, which is run automatically, described here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Completion-Commands.html

I use ido and smex, but the problem occurs in a vanilla Emacs too.

EDIT: I found a hack to fix this. Using `M-x find-function`, I found and copied the function definition of `minibuffer-completion-help` into my `.emacs.d/init.el` file. Then, I renamed the version I copied `my-minibuffer-completion-help` and changed `(with-displayed-buffer-window *Completions*` to `'(with-displayed-buffer-window *Completions*` (putting a quote in front so it is just interpreted as a string. Finally, I overrode the call to `minibuffer-completion-help` by putting

```
(advice-add 'minibuffer-completion-help
        :override #'my-minibuffer-completion-help)
```

after the `my-minibuffer-completion-help` function in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file. There must be a better way.

EDIT 2: quoting out `(message "Making completion list...")` in `my-minibuffer-completion-help` has the added benefit of getting rid of the flicker in autocomplete that is caused by flashing another message during autocomplete. Is it possible to do this another way?

Comment: Please roll back your edit and post that as an answer instead.  The question should remain a question, and posting an answer allows us to vote on whether this answer is good or not. Marking your own answer as accepted will also mark this question as no longer requiring an answer, though you cannot do that immediately.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you just want to set `completion-auto-help` to nil:

```
(setq completion-auto-help nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for is either temporarily modifying [display-buffer-alist](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Temporary-Displays.html#Temporary-Displays), probably setting it to  use `display-buffer-no-window` for *Completions* or `M-x customize-group completion` and setting `Completion Show Help` to `nil`